# Pass parameter in sql select statement as well as in where clause SSIS

Tags: sql, dynamic, ssis

I am trying to get the SQL Command as Variable in a SQL Datasource.

```
"SELECT   " + (DT_WSTR, 25) @[User::valVariable] + " As Value from dbo.MyTable WHERE        (Key= " +  (DT_WSTR, 25)@[User::MyKey] + ")"
```

This is a variable expression, and the value generated for this is :

```
SELECT 1 As Value from dbo.MyTable WHERE (Key = 0)
```

I want the Key value to be passed dynamically which can be set by a ?, however I am unable to do so. Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do articles [like this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/) or [this](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables) help?

Comment: I looked at those. These just help you make variable. I want to use variable within a variable :(

Comment: You could set up a script with two read only variables (valVariable and MyKey) and one read/write variable mySelect (String). Do the select statement concatenation in the script and output mySelect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script component I have working in a data flow. Read Only variables `valVariable` and `MyKey`. ReadWrite variable `MySelect`.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent
    Private StrTemp As String
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        If UCase(Row.Current) = "Y" Then
            StrTemp = "Select " & CStr(Me.Variables.MyVariable) & " as Value  from dbo.Table Where (Key =" & CStr(Me.Variables.MyKey) & ")"
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
        Me.Variables.MySelect = StrTemp
        MsgBox("Select statement: " & Me.Variables.MySelect)
    End Sub
End Class
```